# Error handling in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, error-handling

Can anyone explain what all errors can `App::error` of `Laravel` handles..?

For eg :

1. [404] unable to access the url
2. [500] internal server error

If I have a db connection error or any missing parameter error it doesn't come under this class. How can I handle those major errors..?

Please help in listing all the possible cases..

Comment: It looks like it handles any Exception type object passed to it, but http Exceptions are generated by App::abort and then passed up to App::error

Answer (score 1):

The error handling isn't specifically tied to HTTP status codes.

`App::error` handles any uncaught exceptions. A not found error is just a `NotFoundHttpException`.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-errors

---

A 404 exception can be easily caught with this shortcut method:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    // Example response
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#handling-404-errors

If you don't use the `App::missing` syntax, a not-found type of exception should bubble up to the `App::error` handler.